# How to center a table element within a div?

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this fiddle:

(This question is not the same as the one I asked yesterday. Today, I need to center the innerTable within a div, not within a td element.)

https://jsfiddle.net/dve3413/rxdhcsvc/51/

I'm trying to get 'innertable' to be centered in 'tddiv'. The overflow should be equal on both sides of 'tddiv'. 'innertable' should be horizontally centered and vertical align on top. The overflow should also be centered (equal on left and right). The overflow vertically should all go down. Ideally, css to accomplish this can be contained within 'tddiv' and 'innerTable'.

```
<table class="outerTable" align="center" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td valign=top>
      <div class="tddiv">
        <table class="innerTable" width=300px height=300px border=1 align=center>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

.outerTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  /*   overflow: hidden; */
}

.innerTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.tddiv {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Your inner table is larger than the td which it's in - is that intention?

Comment: Yes, inner table is larger than the td (and the div). The div is restraining the size. I need the overflow to be centered horizontally in the div and going down vertically.

Comment: You asked this yesterday and accepted an answer, why ask it again?

Comment: It's not the same question. This question has the innerTable in a div. Yesterday it was in a td element. The TD element cannot restrict vertical-height as well as a div can.

Comment: centring within any element is done in the same ways so I still class this as a duplicate - as you can see from the answer below (and comments), they have done pretty much the same thing as the person did yesterday in your accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these settings:

```
.innerTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

(`z-index` and `background` don't have to be, I just added them to make the visible result more obvious)

https://jsfiddle.net/afeetdjb/1/

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer you accepted yesterday?

Comment: @Pete I didn't know about it. To be precise, it's not *exactly* the same - in yesterdays answer `margin-left: 50%` was used instead of `position: relative` and `left: 50%`

Comment: It's not the same question, refer to my comments left else where, this is different. Not fair to downgrade.

Comment: @Johannes I was more on about the moving it left - 50% and then transforming backwards.  it's a bit pedantic to be picky about the differences between margin left and left with relative positioning.  Anyway - the previous comment was for dve3413

Comment: yesterdays solution doesn't work inside the td. The TD element grows vertically, that's why I had to put it in a div, to easily restrict the height of the td element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex like this

```css
.outerTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  /*   overflow: hidden; */
}

.innerTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.tddiv {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<table class="outerTable" align="center" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td valign=top>
      <div class="tddiv">
        <table class="innerTable" width=300px height=300px border=1 align=center>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```